# Infinite dimensional Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

From the answers to Mathoverflow Question ["Continuity in Banach space for non-linear maps"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187722/continuity-in-banach-space-for-non-linear-maps), it is possible to infer that the assumption of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem for the autonomous equation
$$
\dot X=F(X), \tag{$\ast$}
$$
could fail to be satisfied even if $F$ is $C^1$: in fact, using the mean-value inequality, the verification of the Cauchy-Lipschitz hypothesis seems to require local boundedness of the derivative, a property which could fail in infinite dimension even when this derivative is continuous.

My question: it is well-known that Peano's theorem (local existence with $F$ continuous, of course without uniqueness) fails in infinite dimensions. Is there a counterexample to existence or uniqueness for ($\ast$) when $F$ is $C^1$ (and of course $F'$ not locally bounded, otherwise CL theorem provides local existence and uniqueness)?

Comment: For a counterexample to Peano's theorem in infinite dimension, check for instance Exercise 18, page IV.41
of the Bourbaki’s volume Fonctions d'une variable réelle.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at the paper I mention in the other question: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01078180

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Indeed, since $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, for every $x_0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in B_{x_0} (\delta)$, $\Vert F' (x) - F' (x_0)\Vert \le 1$. Hence $\Vert F' (x) \Vert \le \Vert F' (x_0) \Vert + 1$ and thus the derivative $F'$ is bounded on the ball $B_{x_0} (\delta)$.
 You can then show the existence of a solution on a small time interval.

Compared to the question ["Continuity in Banach space for non-linear maps"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187722/continuity-in-banach-space-for-non-linear-maps), the radius $\delta > 0$ is not fixed in advance and could be very small.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain this explicitly.